# My main.storyboard's 'default' identity is as xml source code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistoryboard, xcode11

I tried to open the file in a new project, but this didn't do anything. When I right click and 'open as,' I don't see the option of interface builder. The drop down menu in the identity pane also has no interface bulder option.
[Here is a screenshot of the identity pane.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXCoJ.png)

Comment: Did you break it, I mean did you remove some part that make it a "Storyboard"? Could you go back to previous commit/version when it was working?

Comment: I'm not sure what I did that made it break. I just finished editing a view controller 5 minutes before, and when I went back to make another change, the file had already somehow changed. I do not have any previous commits to work towards (I started this app a few hours ago).